# How do i get PHPSESSID using firebug

Tags: php, firebug

How do i get PHPSESSID using firebug
also how do i get it using php scripts
I was able to get it using the Firecookie plugin, but would be interesting to know if i can get it from a php script and run it from a command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open firebug's Net window.
- Make a request to your webserver (refresh the page).
- Check the Response header cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) to send info from within PHP to the Firebug console.